# IAM & Admin (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on google cloud platform and i have faced the issue below.
(I would also like inputs from aws and azure platforms as well.)

- Created a new user in *gsuite* admin console with no roles assigned in gsuite   admin.
- Added that user in gcp IAM console and gave 2 roles : compute security admin and compute network admin at organization level, meaning these permissions are inherited from organization level.

Should my user be able to create projects having only compute secuirty admin and compute network admin roles ?

Comment: This article describes the permissions required to create a project.  https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

Comment: This depends on the IAM roles assigned to the IAM member `domain: example.com` (replace with your G Suite domain). All G Suite members inherit those roles.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** With only those two roles assigned, your user would not be able to create Projects in GCP. You would need to assign a role with the `resourcemanager.projects.create` Permission. The correct role to assign according to the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely#least_privilege) would be `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator`, also known as the "Project Creator" role.

> meaning these permissions are inherited from organization level.

That's not quite what this means. In GCP, resources that are *below* the Organization (e.g. Folders, Projects) will inherit Permissions defined at the Org level, and lower-level resources cannot further restrict permissions already granted at higher levels.

See also:

- [List of predefined Roles in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles)
- [Creating and Managing Projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project)
- [Using Resource Hierarchy for Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control)